# how to use beacon scan nearby api for ios?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, beacon

I'm new to xcode and ios development. I write new project using swift.

I want to add code that scans for beacons and gets the message\attachment of the nearest beacon.
I want the app to also tell when that's beacon is not in range anymore.

1) I saw iBeacons cannot get the beacon's message\attachment?

2) I saw google sample code. I only need the code logic without the ui. 
So I think I'll work on detaching the UI from the logic. 
I just want to be sure:

I can leave only this code?  (remove `let pubMessage: GNSMessage = GNSMessage`)

```
/// Starts publishing the specified name and scanning for nearby devices that are publishing
        /// their names.
        func startSharingWithName(name: String) {
            if let messageMgr = self.messageMgr {
                // Show the name in the message view title and set up the Stop button.
                messageViewController.title = name

                // Publish the name to nearby devices.
                let pubMessage: GNSMessage = GNSMessage(content: name.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding,
                    allowLossyConversion: true))
                publication = messageMgr.publicationWithMessage(pubMessage)

                // Subscribe to messages from nearby devices and display them in the message view.
                subscription = messageMgr.subscriptionWithMessageFoundHandler({[unowned self] (message: GNSMessage!) -> Void in
                    self.messageViewController.addMessage(String(data: message.content, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding))
                    }, messageLostHandler: {[unowned self](message: GNSMessage!) -> Void in
                        self.messageViewController.removeMessage(String(data: message.content, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
                    })
            }
        }
```

as I don't need pub-sub model, just beacons scanning

how come I added viewController code and I see a new UI?

The storyboard just a ui editor for the viewController?

I have read Google [doc](https://google-developers.appspot.com/nearby/messages/ios/get-beacon-messages?hl=ru) and their [github](https://github.com/googlesamples/ios-nearby) and also this [tutorial](https://cocoapods.org/pods/NearbyMessages)

but couldn't get it work in my project.